# File/folder protection that even government cannot break

Tags: software-recommendation, security, encryption

If I have some intellectual property file that under no circumstances my competition can view, what is the best and most secure way to protect them?

I know that there are many encryption apps for Ubuntu, but they all seem basic ones.

Is there any service that I can use that even the best hacker cannot decipher?

Comment: [Mr. Snowden says](http://techcrunch.com/2013/06/17/encrypting-your-email-works-says-nsa-whistleblower-edward-snowden/) use encryption like pgp/gpg. He also says that very determined people could find a way around it, like watching you type the passphrase. But seriously, against just some regular business competition, don't put all your info on the web voluntarily and keep your doors locked.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, I believe there isn't any encryption which can be deemed 100% secure. The reason for that is, it is human made. Despite that the evolution of hardware in the past 20 years has prooven that nothing is secure forever. Best example is here the long time deemed secure md5 one way encryption.

But back to your question, your best security is physical disconection from the internet, and maybe using even GnuPG to encrypt , but then use a very big key and store the key on a USB apart from the file.

And when you now think "Ok, im good at 'whatever programming language, you name it', I'm going to implement myself some encryptions", you should have a decent knowlegde of that whole encryption process, because a wrong made implementation is as bad as no encryption at all.

See encryption more like house door locks, they are made to prolong the time and efford to invest to break in.

So best course of action:

- keep your file disconnected, store it on an external harddrive.
- keep your file encrypted.
- use a large keypair (4096 size)
- store your private key apart from the harddrive on a second medium.
- if you fear your competitor breaks into your home/company, get big bad
  dogs and an alarm system or store the drive with file in a bank deposit.

Comment: Another option is a bank deposit.

Comment: Updated my answer to include your sugesstion.

Comment: double negative - "don't believe there isn't"

Comment: Corrected, english is not my native tongue so im happy if someone points that out.